# Reprint a String array Java

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

I have a string array

```
 "Ben", "Jim", "Ken"
```

how can I print the above array 3 times to look like this:

```
 "Ben", "Jim", "Ken"
 "Jim", "Ben", "Ken"
 "Ken", "Jim", "Ben"
```

I just want each item in the initial array to appear as the first element. The order the other items appear does not matter.

more examples

**Input**

```
"a","b","c","d"
```

**output**

```
"a","b","c","d"
"b","a","c","d"
"c","b","a","d"
"d","a","c","d"
```

**Method signature**

```
 public void printArray(String[] s){
 }
```

Comment: Is there anything you've already tried? Please try to make an attempt to try it before asking a question here. It's a common beginner's mistake, but just remember this website is not meant for people to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void printArray(String[] s){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("\"" + s[i] + "\",");
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                System.out.print("\"" + s[j] + "\",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide explanations or comments to/in your code, otherwise, despite this being quite basic, it's meaningless to someone who doesn't know how the code works.

Comment: @AlmightyR I only answered the question because it was too easy. If you think it's insufficient, feel free to upvote another answer or write your own. If you think my answer is totally unhelpful, feel free to downvote or flag it.

Comment: shmosel, while your answer is definitely *not* *"totally unhelpful"*, it does only provide a code solution, without providing any explanation or context of *how* or *why* the solution works. You need not more than common-sense to deduce that if the OP didn't use code similar to yours, it's a safe bet that he *simply doesn't understand **how** to*, otherwise, he would have reached a solution on his own, and there would be no such question. Basically, by providing just *code* rather than an *answer*, you're doing the OP a disservice IMO, and delaying his learning. So, indeed, -1.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than give you straight-up code, I'm going to try and explain the theory/mathematics for this problem.

The two easiest ways I can come up with to solve this problem is to either

- Cycle through all the elements
- Pick an element and list the rest

The first method would require you to iterate through the indices and then iterate through all the elements in the array and loop back to the beginning when necessary, terminating when you return to the original element.

The second method would require you to iterate through the indices, print original element, then proceed to iterate through the array from the beginning, skipping the original element.

As you can see, both these methods require two loops (as you are iterating through the array twice)

In pseudo code, the first method could be written as:

```
for (i = array_start; i < array_end; i++) {
    print array_element[i]
    for (j = i + 1; j != i; j++) {
        if (j is_larger_than array_end) {
            set j equal to array_start
        }
        print array_element[j]
    }
}
```

In pseudo code, the second method could be written as:

```
for (i = array_start; i < array_end; i++) {
    print array_element[i]
    for (j = array_start; j < array_end; j++) {
        if (j is_not_equal_to i) {
            print array_element[j]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
        for(int j=i;j<s.length+i;j++) {
            System.out.print(s[j%(s.length)]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Using **mod** is approppiate for this question. The indexes of the printed values for your first example are like this;

0 1 2

1 2 0

2 0 1

so if you write them like the following and take mod of length of the array (3 in this case) you will reach solution.

0 1 2

1 2 3

2 3 4

Comment: Please provide explanations or comments to/in your code, otherwise, despite this being quite basic, it's meaningless to someone who doesn't know how the code works.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question so while I feel I shouldn't answer it, I'll give a simple hint. You are looking for an algorithm which will give all permutations (combinations) of the "for loop index" of the elements not the elements themselves. so if you have three elements a,b,c them the index is 0,1,2 and all we need is a way to generate permutations of 0,1,2 so this leads to a common math problem with a very simple math formula.

See here: https://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/permutations-vs-combinations-how-to-calculate-arrangements/